# how to check if a passcode or screenlock is set in Android?

Tags: android

Hi friend's i am new in Android

> how to check if a passcode or screenlock is set in Android.

Is there any public API to figure this out. MY current application stores some secure data so it's important to know from the business logic of the application.please suggest me something.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
int patternsetting = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED);
```

0 means has No pattern, 1 means has pattern.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED

Comment: @Roy_joy Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask